# Jquery .load - get <div> featured products (opencart) from index.php to index.html same domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

javascript is definately not one of my strong points and normally I get by quite well. however.

what i have is (for purpose of information) site http://mystore.co.uk which by default will lead you to index.html as the home page.

I then have index.php which is my opencart store.

on index.php i have a featured products module installed and what I wish to do is take that entire div and place it onto my index.html page.

What is the javascript .load function script that I need to use to do this. I have been looking for an answer but I think I have propably overlooked it several times due to frustration and confusion. any help you can offer would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using a hidden iframe?

Comment: I havn't is the simple answer

Comment: You could also create a hidden div, and use jQuery.load() function to load the data into there, and then use a selector to pull out the div.

Comment: Just to clarify - these two pages are on the same domain. so there is no need for curl.php as far as I am aware.

If you could be kind enough to write out the code I would need to use for that, it would be a great help

Comment: Ok, thats good, but you can do this all client side. Try the ajax first. The solution I provided above with the hidden div

Comment: Try my solution below. I think you should be good.

Comment: @AlexShilman: If there is a problem with a post, please describe the problem in detail, instead of just posting "what have you tried". See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134) on whether "what have you tried" comments are acceptable and alternatives to "what have you tried". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, Assuming #yourhiddenDiv is in index.html and #yourdiv is the one you want to fetch from index.php, and both files are on the same domain:

```
$('#yourhiddenDiv').load('index.php #yourdiv').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: they are the same domain yes. and this has helped immensly - thank you